# How can I get sum of tasks that belongs to project in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have Tasks that belongTo the List, and a Lists that belongsTo Project.
I have no task-project relation.
I need to find the sum of all the tasks in the project with **whereHas function**, and display that sum inside the Project.vue component.

This is task table:

```
  Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('list_id');
            $table->foreign('list_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('task_lists')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->boolean('completed')
                ->default(false);
            $table->string('description');

        });
```

This is list table:

```
    Schema::create('task_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
        $table->foreign('project_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('projects')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

Relations in Project Model:

```
public function lists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TaskList::class);
}
```

Relations in TaskList model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

Relation in Task model:

```
   public function list()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TaskList::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use `hasManyThrough` as mentioned in rest of the answers and  that's obviously an elegant way to do it.

But if you want to don't want to do it that way, you can use this.

```
$tasks_count = Task::whereHas('list', function($query) use($project_id){
          $query->whereHas('project', function($query) use($project_id){
              $query->where('id', $project_id); 
          });
      })
   ->with([
     'list' => function($query) use($project_id){
          $query->whereHas('project', function($query) use($project_id){
              $query->where('id', $project_id); 
          });
      },
      'list.project' => function($query) use($project_id){
         $query->where('id', $project_id);
      },
  ])
  ->count();
```

Comment: Thank you!
I wasn’t allowed to make new relationships,and I had to use hasMany, so you helped me a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `HasManyThrough` relationship for `tasks` on the `Project` model.

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Task::class, TaskList::class);
}
```

You should then be able to go `$project->tasks->count()`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

To get all the tasks for a project you can add a `hasManyThorugh` relationship. [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Task', 'App\TaskList');
    }
```

In your code simply call the above defined relationship to get the `Tasks` in a `Project`:

```
$project->tasks()->count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply do [if not using hasManyThrough]

```
$project=Project::find($id);
$project->lists()->list()->count();
```

Comment: Watch out with the use of `()` when accessing relationships. If you are using any eager loading this will create new queries regardless of what you have already loaded ...

Comment: we can use with() to reduce number of queries then ?

Comment: By using has many through you can do something like `Project::with(['tasks'])` or  even as is `Project::with(['lists.tasks'])` to eager load the relationships to keep the query count low.

Comment: Thanks. Was just giving a way to count them . Did not think about performance issue